# Overloading operators?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I'm studying overloading operator with this program (taken by http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/):

```
class CVector {
public:
    int x, y;
    CVector() {};
    CVector(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector operator + (const CVector&);
};

CVector CVector::operator+ (const CVector& param) {
    CVector temp;
    cout << x << " " << param.x  << endl; //my addition
    temp.x = x + param.x;
    temp.y = y + param.y;
    return temp;
}

int Desperate2() {
    CVector bar(1, 2);
    CVector foo(3, 4);
    CVector result;
    result = bar+foo;
    cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why the `x` that there is in `temp.x = x+param.x` is the value of `bar` and `param.x` the value of `foo`. And if we write `result = foo + bar` the vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result = bar+foo;` could also be written as `result = bar.operator+(foo);`.

So in the case of `bar + foo` we are calling the member function `operator+` on bar and giving it the parameter `foo`.

We could write it as follows and it's the same principle.

```
class CVector {
public:
    int x, y;
    CVector() {};
    CVector(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    CVector add(const CVector&);
};

CVector CVector::add(const CVector& param) {
    CVector temp;
    cout << x << " " << param.x  << endl; //my addition
    temp.x = x + param.x;
    temp.y = y + param.y;
    return temp;
}

int Desperate2() {
    CVector bar(1, 2);
    CVector foo(3, 4);
    CVector result;
    result = bar.add(foo);
    cout << result.x << ',' << result.y << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The fact that `bar+foo` calls the member function `operator+` could be considered syntactic sugar.